# Python plotting points on a city map

Tags: python, plot, pandas, gis

I am not really familiar with GIS systems in python. I am looking for a library to do the following:

Lets say I have a pandas data frame with one column of street addresses and another of labeled categorical or numerical data. Something like the following for San Francisco:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['1 Dr Carlton B Goodlett Place','1390 Market Street','1100 Fillmore St' ],
                 'Type': ['G', 'G','C']})
```

And I want to plot them on a map of San Francisco with the 'Type' column being in red for the data in 'G' and blue for 'C'. How would I a simple plot like this? How would I also include streets on the map? Can an simple example be provided?

I found a library called [Geopy](https://code.google.com/p/geopy/wiki/GettingStarted) to change the data to longitude & latitude if it helps to convert the data. Also read that `matplotlib` can do this with `basemap` but it is for areas larger than cities.

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of ways to plot data in a map. 
The geopy lib includes geocoding libraries to convert addresses to gps coordinates but you still need to take a look at the license (for example google asks you to buy a license or only use the service with their maps). An easy way to obtain a map background is using a free tile service here are some useful urls:

http://leafletjs.com/ ("free" js library for plotting)

http://www.openstreetmap.org/ ("free" background maps)

Comment: Nothing BSD or opensource I can just load into python and just plot?